# VBA Macro to compare 2 files

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro to compare the values from one column from first file to one column in another file. If the value from the other file is not found then the macro should the insert the a line and then copy the missing values.
At the moment I am getting a problem as the debugger is showing application or object defined error. Any ideas what the problem might be?

The code I have at the moment is this:

```
Sub CheckC()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh1 As Variant
Dim sh2 As Variant
i = 6

sh1 = Application.Workbooks("workbookc.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet name").Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(6, 3).End(xlDown)).Value
sh2 = Application.Workbooks("workbookm.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(6, 3).End(xlDown)).Value

For Each val_sh1 In sh1
    flag = False
    For Each val_sh2 In sh2
        i = i + 1
        If val_sh1 = val_sh2 Then
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next val_sh2
    If flag = False Then

    Workbooks("workbookm.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9)).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Workbooks("workbookc.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet name").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("workbookm.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9))

    End If

Next val_sh1

End Sub
```

Edit update:
Thank you all for your answers, I have come up with some solution, using your suggestions.
The final code looks like this:

```
 Sub CheckC()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
 Set ws1 = Workbooks("workbookc.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet name")
 Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet
 Set ws2 = Workbooks("workbookm.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Dim sh1 As Range
 Dim sh2 As Range
 i = 5
 counter = 0
 ws1.Activate
 Set sh1 = ws1.Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(6, 3).End(xlDown))
 ws2.Activate
 Set sh2 = ws2.Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(6, 3).End(xlDown))

 For Each val_sh1 In sh1
   flag = False
   i = i + 1
   For Each val_sh2 In sh2

        If val_sh1 = val_sh2 Then
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next val_sh2
    If flag = False Then

    ws2.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9)).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ws1.Activate
    ws1.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws2.Activate
    ws2.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next val_sh1

MsgBox counter & " new rows were added to workbookm"
ws2.Activate
Range("A1").Value = "workbookm updated on " &      Now()
End Sub
```

It is working as it should.

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of your code, but currently your variables `sh1` and `sh2` aren't sheets or ranges but just the values of one of the selected cells in the ranges.

Of course this is going to cause issues when you try to loop through them.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not that proficient in programming. When I change the declaration of those 2 variables to range it still shows the same problem. It is as if the program cannot access the other workbook.

Comment: If you try to select a sheet that is not active your will get an error. Make the sheet active by clicking on it and then try running it.

Comment: It would slowly go through some lines until I make a reference to the other workbook at which point I need to activate the other workbook. So what is the issue here? I have both of the files opened at the same time and I shouldn't have to activate it manually every time, isn't that right?

Comment: You can activate the sheet with code using `Workbooks("workbookm.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCB is right in saying that the problem is with your sh1 and sh2 variables. Generally speaking you should split the whole thing into more variables defining workbook, worksheet and range levels, then you can refer to values on the range level. If you define it properly, you do not need to activate the workbooks as you loop, instead you are directly referring to data in those workbooks.

See the below example of a code that I've got. It's not exactly what you are looking for, but it should be a sufficient basis for you to modify it so that it suits your needs. It compares values from wkb2 column A with values in column A of wkb1, if there are any missing values it's going to append them at the end of column A in wkb1. You can create two test files with some data in columns A, copy the below macro into the one that will be assigned to wkb2 and run to see what it does. I hope it'll help you.

```
Sub compareTwoColumns()

'Define starting row and column
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
r = 2
c = 1

'Define workbooks
Dim wkb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wkb2 As Excel.Workbook
'wkb2 should be the workbook that holds this macro
Set wkb2 = Application.Workbooks("testWKB2.xlsm")
Set wkb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEMP\testWKB1.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)

'Define variables for worksheets
Dim sh1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Excel.Worksheet
Set sh1 = wkb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = wkb2.Worksheets("fnd")

'Define ranges
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = sh1.Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c).End(xlDown))
wkb2.Activate
sh2.Activate
Set rng2 = sh2.Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c).End(xlDown))

Dim list1 As New Collection
Dim found As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each i In rng2

    found = False

    For Each j In rng1
        If j.Value = i.Value Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If Not found Then
            list1.Add (i.Value)
    End If

Next i

Dim string1 As String
For Each n In list1
    string1 = string1 & Chr(13) & n
Next n

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Inserting missing rows

If list1.Count > 0 Then

    MsgBox "The following rows will be inserted: " & Chr(13) & string1

    'Activate target worksheet and activate the last cell in column A
    sh1.Activate
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Activate

    'Add missing rows at the bottom of the column
    For Each m In list1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = CStr(m)
    Next m
Else
    MsgBox "No missing rows found"
End If

End Sub
```